# Identifying a instance of a ViewController in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application, I have two View Controllers - a UIViewController and UITableViewController.
Now, in my TableViewController implementation I need to retrieve some data from the UIViewController (a property - array). The array it's synthesized, so what I'm actually doing is that in the implementation of the UITableViewController, I'm creating a instance of my UIViewController, an array, and just set the array to [myUIViewController getTheArray]. I know it won't work this way, it's just retrieving nil, but in my VC it's actually full of data. I am stuck at this point, I could've tried with the performSegueWithIdentifier method, but these views are not directly connected via a segue to each other. They are embedded in a Tab Bar View, and my ViewController has absolutely nothing to do with my TableViewController.
Any idea on how to make this work properly?
Thanks.

```
@interface classA : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Playlist* playlist;

-(Playlist*) getTheCurrentPlaylist;
@end

@implementation classA

@synthesize playlist = _playlist;
// add data to _playlist
-(Playlist*) getTheCurrentPlaylist{
return _playlist;
}
@end
```

now, to classB

```
@interface classB : UITableViewController
@property (strong ,nonatomic) Playlist* playlistTab;
@end

@implementation classB
@synthesize playlistTab = _playlistTab;

-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
classA *cla = [[classA alloc] init];
// what has to be done here?
_playlistTab = [cla getTheCurrentPlaylist];
}
```

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I wish i could understand what you tried to say. Can you try to make it more clear, maybe with little code snippets ?

Comment: The code is now in the main post.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you set break points and verified that the method is getting called? Have you verified that at the break point, when it is called, that the returned value is not nil?

Comment: Yeah I actually used an NSLog to display some data from _playlistTab and all I got is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure I understand what you mean so please do comment if I misunderstood something. Also, I'm fairly new to iOS development myself.

Ok, so you have a Tab bar controller with a UIViewController and a UITableViewController. Your implementation of a UIViewController has some data and your UITableViewController needs access to that data. You **can't** just create a new classA. You need to refer to the instance of the classA that you created and put into the tab bar.

One thing you can do is to have the AppDelegate be aware of the UIViewController (i.e. AppDelegate has a property that references the UIViewController. Then in you UITableViewController, you can do something like this to access the UIViewController:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDel = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myUIViewController.playlist;
```

Sounds like a real simple application so probably using something like Core Data might be overly complicated. Another way you can do above, is to have your instance of ClassA set a values of some [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) then have ClassB read from that. Or simply just create a property of your AppDelegate that gets written to by UIViewController and read from your table view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get the error "property 'myUIViewController' is not found on object of type 'MyAppDelegate*".

Comment: Well, you can't just copy past that code... Ok, a) in you appdel create a property called playlist. b) from classA use the code above to get appDel, then set the playlist when playlist is save/changed. c) finally from classb, use the code above again to get appDel and read from playlist.

Comment: Sir, you're a life saver! It began working like a clock! I just had to use the appDelegate.playlist (without the UIViewController). Many many thanks!